# Joomla doesn't store Tags in custom extension

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm building a custom extension which is based on modified version of **com_weblinks** extension and there's one thing, that i simply cannot figure out.

Joomla 3 supports Tags functionality, I've followed this guide (http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension) to create my own content type in #__content_types, also joomla model, joomla xml form and JTable structure are the same as in com_weblinks.

It works fine in com_weblinks, but in my extension it simply doesn't store any tags. After hours of research I've managed to find out, that in my extension JTable class doesn't find any Observers in method **JTable::store**. In other words **$this->_observers** is an empty object and in com_weblinks it returns Tags observer object.

I wasn't able to find, any differences, which causes to load observers in weblinks table, and skip them in my table.

Any ideas would be highly appreaciated.

Comment: Hmm may be [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-general/KWCTyD1Ga_8/gy6hwlVd-nEJ) will help.

Comment: Yeah, I've already read this one. I'm trying to find out what causes observer to be attached in weblinks extension, and what I am missing.

Comment: What exact version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Latest Joomla version 3.2.1

Comment: THe problem is that the way tags was changed (don't ask me why) core components and extensions act differently because the core components are registered as observers directly but you need to do it indirectly with a non core extension.  I would go download a tags supporting extension from the jed and copy what they did.

Comment: Thanks @Elin for a good idea :) I'll do some research on that and post here how did it go. Anyway it's a weird solution to define observers only for core extensions...

Comment: On this page http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension#Modify_your_component.27s_table_class_.28or_classes_if_you_have_multiple_tables.29 someone has added "For joomla 3.2 I needed this line: ( Dont forget to replace weblinks by your component name )

JObserverMapper::addObserverClassToClass('JTableObserverTags', 'WeblinksTableWeblink', array('typeAlias' => 'com_weblinks.weblink'));"

Comment: do you have any posthook action in relevant controller?